# How to detect and clasify materials in an image using data science/computer vision?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-comparison

If a picture contained plastic, cloth, metal etc. how can one train the computer to segment out materials of the same type. Please add if any other method can be used as a starting point for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Material recognition is an active research area in computer vision. Google "material recognition computer vision" for a list of recent papers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a semantic issue to solve first.

- Where does plastic that is painted with a metallic paint sit?
- What about a plastic that is textured to look like cloth?
- What about fabric that is woven metal fibre?

Rather than describe by material, you need to start defining by visual properties like reflectivity, surface texture etc

Comment: like in a picture of a garbage dump

Comment: or just a sheet of metal, plastic bottle placed in the side and cloth laying on the other side.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I disagree. The first part of an answer is to help state the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It an evolving area . I would suggest you to read some papers. You can use google or Google Scholar for that.Use http://bfy.tw/220q

Few approaches are :

- Using Bayesian Framework
- SVM
- Neural Networks